# Use value of superclass in instance in Swift

Tags: swift, signalr, instance

I am trying to write a chat application and I am using SignalR for this. I recently started to refactor the code to use a handler for the SignalR/SwiftR functions. I am creating an instance, when I call the SignalR handler from the chat viewController. Now I have a function, which is triggered inside the handler instance and from there I am trying to execute a function in the viewController. I tried to do this with an instance. But now I don't have any data in my arrayMessage because I am creating a new instance of the class. Is there a way to get the array of the normal class?

If not, what's the best way to execute this function?

This should execute the recieveMessage:

```
 chatHub.on("CommunityMessage") { args in
            if let m: AnyObject = args![0] as AnyObject!{
            SignalRViewController.instance.recieveMessage(m: m)
            }
        }
```

recieveMessage function, where I don't have data in the arrayMessage:

```
     func recieveMessage(m : AnyObject){
        let message = m.object(forKey: "Message") as! String
        let index = (self.arrayMessage.count - 1)
        print(self.arrayMessage)
     }
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to call the callback function "receiveMessage" on your VC from somewhere other than the VC right?
Would it be possible to use a delegate pattern?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I thought of using a delegate but didn't quite understand them yet, so I was hoping to get it working with a instance

Comment: Where do you execute the first block of code? Usually you would trigger e.g. a service class from the VC where it passes itself as delegate. If this doesn't work e.g. if you define the callbacks once when the app is launched then you could use notifications

Comment: The first block is executed, whenever the server executes CommunityMessage, so inside the SignalR Handler.

Comment: Ok then I'd post a notification via the NotificationCenter.default and pass the message. In your VC you then subscribe for this notification with your receive-message method (you have to change the signature up a bit) and then parse the passed message.

Comment: Okey, I will try to use notifications

Comment: @TMob How can I pass the parameter m with notifications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your chathub-callback you can post a notification with the message attached

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "ChatHubMessageReceived"), object: m)
```

In the ViewController you can then subscribe yourself to the message

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, 
                                       selector: #selector(receiveMessage), 
                                       name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "ChatHubMessageReceived"), 
                                       object: nil)
```

You will have to adjust the method signature to one that takes a notification

```
func recieveMessage(notification: Notification) {
    let message = notification.object
}
```